# UnsupportedOperationException is thrown with Lombok Builder annotation

Tags: java, list, runtimeexception, lombok, builder-pattern

I am using Lombok for my project.
My model looks like:

```
@Builder
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
public class ScreenDefinitionDTO {
    @Singular
    private List<ScreenDeclaration> screens;
}
```

I want to do next operation:

```
String screenName = ctx.screenName().getText();
ScreenDeclaration declaration = ParsingUtils
                .buildScreenDeclaration(StringUtils.trim(screenName));
```

Where instance is created:

```
public static ScreenDefinitionDTO buildEmptyScreenDTO() {
    return ScreenDefinitionDTO.builder()
            .screens(new ArrayList<>())
            .build();
}
```

Finally, I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

When I changed creating the instance without Lombok builder pattern everything is fine:

```
public static ScreenDefinitionDTO buildEmptyScreenDTO() {
    return new ScreenDefinitionDTO(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

***I couldn't understand what is wrong with Lombok's builder pattern?***

Comment: I'd bet, there's more to see in the stack trace. Something like `Collection$UnmodifiableList` or alike, which sort of explains it.

Comment: @maaartinus I haven't seen anything related to this kind of output.

Comment: I was wrong. I configure `lombok.singular.useGuava=true` and get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollection.java:221)`, but `Collections` simply relies on inheriting the throwing method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/916)

> Lombok `@Builder` is primarily meant for immutables (and uses either
>   Collections.unmodifiableList or Guava's ImmutableList

that's why you have `UnsupportedOperationException`

For greater certainty reproduce full code pattern where you have exception please.

Comment: Does any workarounds exist for it? Skipping Lombok's builder is working, however, it isn't so convenient.

Comment: @nazar_art AFAIK no, but what about using an immutable object? Sometimes, it's a bad idea, but sometimes, it's not. There's also `toBuilder` (if you allowed it in the `@Builder` annotation), which gives you a mutable object again.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
@Builder
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
public class ScreenDefinitionDTO {
    @Builder.Default
    private List<ScreenDeclaration> screens = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This way you are telling lombok to, on build, initialize `screens` with an empty `ArrayList`.

Comment: How did you solved this ? I am getting ``Singular.Default cannot be resolved to a type``

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped "Singular". The correct is "Builder", as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @fbokovikov the `@Builder` annotation uses immutables so when you try to add an element in the list an exception is thrown.

```
dto.getScreens().add(new ScreenDeclaration()) // throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

If you set a breakpoint to see the value returned by `dto.getScreens()` you can see its type is `Collections$EmptyList`. If you use the constructor of the DTO then the type is `ArrayList` and the exception is not thrown.